# JQuery draggable object position save in SQL

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

Due to the corona-crysis my friends and me can not meet up, so i want to play a little game with them. Everybody can move an object on my website and when the page is reloaded, the latest position of the object will be shown.

Im am working with asp.net c# on my server. With JQuery i make an img draggable, now i want to save the position of that object to my mssql server. ive read some blogs and tried my best to make it work, but somehow i am stuck... here is my code:

on the .aspx web form:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Prototyp.aspx.cs" Inherits="Login_Website_Neu.Prototyp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<script src="Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js" type="text/javascript">></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript">></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" type="text/javascript">></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.slim.js" type="text/javascript">></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript">></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.intellisense.js" type="text/javascript">></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js" type="text/javascript">></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript">></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(function() {
    $("#d1").draggable(
    {
      drag: function(event, ui) {
        $("#d1").css("opacity", "0.6"); // Semi-transparent when dragging
      },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
        //nachricht(ui.offset.left, ui.offset.top, $('#d1').attr('id'));
        saveCoords(ui.absolutePosition.left, ui.absolutePosition.top, $('#test').attr('id'));
        $("#d1").css("opacity", "1.0"); // Full opacity when stopped
      },
      cursor: "move"
    });
    });

    //function nachricht(x, y, i) {
    //    alert(x + ' test ' + y + i)
    //}

    function saveCoords(x, y, el, id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Prototyp.aspx.cs/SaveCoords",
    data: "{x: '" + x + "', y: '" + y + "', element: '" + el + "', userid: '1'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
      if (response.d != '1') {
        alert('Not Saved!');
      }
    },
    error: function(response) {
      alert(response.responseText);
    }
  });
}

</script> 

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server"> 

<div> 

  <img src="Bilder/Mustard.png" alt="" id="d1"  width="30" height="30"  runat="server" />

</div> 

</form> 
</body>
```

and on the aspx.cs codebehind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Login_Website_Neu
{
    public partial class Prototyp : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for SaveCoords
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.

    [ScriptService]
    public class Coordinates : WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public int SaveCoords(int x, int y, string element, int userid)
        {
            string connect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DarfAlles"].ConnectionString;
            int result = 0;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connect))
            {
                string query = "UPDATE [Benutzerdefinierte_Kader].[dbo].[Coords] SET xPos = @xPos, yPos = @yPos WHERE Element = @Element AND UserID = @UserID";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("xPos", x);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("yPos", y);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Element", element);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserID", userid);
                    conn.Open();
                    result = (int)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }


        [WebMethod]

        public DataTable GetSavedCoords(int userid)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string connect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DarfAlles"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connect))
            {
                string query = "SELECT xPos, yPos, Element FROM [Benutzerdefinierte_Kader].[dbo].[Coords] WHERE UserID = @UserID";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserID", userid);
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }

        public partial class PersistDraggable : Page

        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Coordinates coords = new Coordinates();
                DataTable dt = coords.GetSavedCoords(1);
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    HtmlControl ctl = (HtmlControl)this.FindControl(row["element"].ToString());
                    if (ctl != null)
                    {
                        ctl.Style.Add("left", row["xPos"].ToString() + "px");
                        ctl.Style.Add("top", row["yPos"].ToString() + "px");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not add both `.min.js` and `.js` files, they contain the same javascript functions. You can check https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources

Comment: thank you alot for your answer! i will delete one of them!

somehow the object i am dragging stops at the first drop. so i think something else must be wrong in the saveCoords. Do you have any idea or suggestion?

Comment: I think there must be a problem at passing variables from AJAX to Code Behind. Can somebody agree with that? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use 
position object to get the X and Y coordinate.Because when we drop the image, `absolutePosition` is undefined,No such property is present.
Hence absolutePosition.left and absolutePosition.right throwing error.

Use  below code to test

```
stop: function (event, ui) {
            alert(ui.position.top+";"+ui.position.left);
}
```